# Secure Canvas URL of Facebook App with free hosting

Tags: facebook

I am very new to building applications on Facebook's platform. I don't own a hosting space nor a domain name, so i'm using free hosting/domain name at the moment and I need to create a Facebook app for a school project. However, there is this Secure Canvas URL field that I have to fill. Should the free hosting service have a SSL certificate (or whatever it is) in order to be able to load my app? I'm using 000webhost.com ? Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes from November 1st 2011 the facebook application should have the secure connection 
for their applications 
Here you may find some answer [I dont have secure canvas url (I can't afford for https connection)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/11177540/1375001)

Answer (score 0):

Forward is great for testing/developing facebook apps. It has a free trial:

https://forwardhq.com/in-use/facebook